# stuck trying to fix bad Android 6.0 update

Tags: boot

When manually updating my Nexus 9 (Wifi) to Android 6.0, I forgot to flash the cache.img and vendor.img images. Now my Nexus 9 is stuck at the Google boot screen (just says Google, no animation). How do I get the Nexus 9 back to the state where I can re-flash images manually again (i.e., "flashboot flash...")?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply booting in fastboot mode (I already was there). Apparently, booting in fastboot → plugging in the USB cable → waiting a couple of minutes for the device to be detected by ADB (`adb devices`) works best (otherwise it won't list the device). I was then able to install Android 6.0 successfully via fastboot commands (USB debugging and OEM unlocking were previously enabled and the bootloader unlocked).

```
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-flounder-3.48.0.0135.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash boot boot.img
mfastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
fastboot flash cache cache.img
fastboot reboot
```

`mfastboot` was used instead of `fastboot` to flash the `system.img` file because the latter gave an "could not allocate -1995847632" error message (it can't handle big image files).

I will re-lock the bootloader later.